# How to set python scripts launch locations in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, windows-10

I thought it will be as simple as adding these locations to Path or PYTHONPATH. I added them to PYTHONPATH and added PYTHONPATH to Path.

When running `SET` of window's terminal I can see my newly set paths;

```
    E:\Tests> SET
    Path=E:\Tests\PythonTests
    PYTHONPATH=E:\Tests\PythonTests
```

(I simplified the list for readability)

I then create a  very simple python file test.py inside E:\Tests\PythonTests with a single line:

```
    print ("Hello world")
```

Now, if I `cd \Tests\PythonTests` I can run it successfully:

```
    E:\Tests\PythonTests> python test.py
    Hello world
```

If I `cd \Tests` I can:

```
    E:\Tests> python pythonTests/test.py
    Hello world
```

But if I try

```
    E:\Tests> python test.py
    python: can't open file 'test.py': [error 2] No such file or directory
```

Python version:

```
    E:\Tests\PythonTests>python --version
    Python 3.8.0
```

Am I'm missing something? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PYTHONPATH` env var does not control where the `python` command searches for arbitrary Python programs. It controls where modules/packages are searched for. Google "pythonpath environment variable" for many explanations what the env var does. This is from `python --help`:

```
PYTHONPATH   : ':'-separated list of directories prefixed to the
               default module search path.  The result is sys.path.
```

Specifying a file from which to read the initial Python script is not subject to any env var manipulation. In other words, running `python my_prog.py` only looks in the CWD for *my_prog.py*. It does not look at any other directory.